# I am stuck on getting a previous value

Tags: sql

[image: Example pic]

I have been working on this SQL code for a bit and I cannot get it to display like I want. I have an operation that we send parts outside of our business but there is no time stamp on when that operation sent out.

I am taking the previous operation's last labor date and the purchase order creation date to try and find out how long it takes that department to issued a purchase order.

I have tried LAST_Value to add to my query. I have even played with LAG and couldn't get a anything but errors.

```
SELECT
    JobOpDtl.JobNum,
    JobOpDtl.OprSeq,
    JobOpDtl.OpDtlDesc,
    LastValue.ClockInDate,
    LastValue.LastValue
FROM Erp.JobOpDtl
LEFT OUTER JOIN Erp.LaborDtl ON
    LaborDtl.JobNum = JobOpDtl.JobNum
    and LaborDtl.OprSeq = JobOpDtl.OprSeq
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
                Select
                    LaborDtl.JobNum,
                    LaborDtl.OprSeq,
                    MAX(LaborDtl.ClockInDate) as ClockInDate,
                    LAST_VALUE (LaborDtl.ClockInDate) OVER (PARTITION BY OprSeq ORDER BY JobNum) as LastValue
                FROM Erp.LaborDtl
                GROUP BY
                    LaborDtl.JobNum,
                    LaborDtl.OprSeq,
                    LaborDtl.ClockInDate
            ) as LastValue ON
                JobOpDtl.JobNum = LastValue.JobNum
                and JobOpDtl.OprSeq = LastValue.OprSeq

WHERE JobOpDtl.JobNum = 'PA8906'
GROUP BY 
    JobOpDtl.JobNum,
    LastValue.OprSeq,
    JobOpDtl.OpDtlDesc,
    JobOpDtl.OprSeq,
    LastValue.ClockInDate,
    LastValue.LastValue
```

No errors, just not displaying how I am wanting it.

I would like it to display the OperSeq with the previous OperSeq last transaction date.

Comment: please write some details with table structure and data.

Comment: How do you mean? Like what the table contains? nvarchar(8), (14), int, etc?

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out how these values relate, could you give us the relevant fields for 3 or 4 rows of JobOptDtl, maybe a dozen corresponding rows of LaborDtl, and the output you expect? Maybe add a brief explanation of the fields like OperSeq (how does it vary and what does it mean) and explain where labor date and purchase order date are and how we identify them.

Comment: I  have added a pic to maybe help explain the tables. We create a job (jobopdtl.jobnum) and each job has an operation (jobopdtl.oprseq) number as well as a description (jobopdtl.opdtldesc), etc.

Comment: I will be adding the Purchase Order tables. That is a simple join and have not gotten past this yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic function you want is LAG (as you suggested) but you need to wrap it in a COALESCE. Here is a sample code that illustrates the concept

```
SELECT * INTO #Jobs
FROM (VALUES ('P1','Step1', '2019-04-01'), ('P1','Step2', '2019-04-02')
    , ('P1','Step3', '2019-04-03'), ('P1','Step4', NULL), 
    ('P2','Step1', '2019-04-01'), ('P2','Step2', '2019-04-03')
    , ('P2','Step3', '2019-04-06'), ('P2','Step4', NULL)
) as JobDet(JobNum, Descript, LastDate)

SELECT * 
    , COALESCE( LastDate, LAG(LastDate,1) 
        OVER(PARTITION BY JobNum 
        ORDER BY COALESCE(LastDate,GETDATE()))) as LastValue
FROM #Jobs
ORDER BY JobNum, Descript

DROP TABLE #Jobs
```

To apply it to your specific problem, I'd suggest using a COMMON TABLE EXPRESSION that replaces LastValue and using that instead of the raw table for your queries.

Your example picture doesn't match any tables you reference in your code (it would help us significantly if you included code that created temp tables matching those referenced in your code) so this is a guess, but it will be something like this:

```
;WITH cteJob as (
    SELECT JobNum, OprSeq, OpDtlDesc, ClockInDate
    , COALESCE( LastValue, LAG(LastValue,1) 
        OVER(PARTITION BY JobNum 
        ORDER BY COALESCE(LastValue,GETDATE()))) as LastValue
    FROM Erp.JobOptDtl
) SELECT * 
FROM cteJob as J 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN LaborDtl as L 
        on J.JobNum = JobNum 
            AND J.OprSeq = L.OprSeq
```

BTW, if you clean up your question to provide a better example of your data (i.e. SELECT INTO sttements like in the start of my answer that produce tables that correspond to the tables in your code instead of an image of an excel file) I might be able to get you closer to what you need, but hopefully this is enough to get you on the right track and it's the best I can do with what you've provided so far.

Comment: Thank you! I will work on my explanations to better help.